# android media player local object many different sounds should I release?

Tags: android, media-player

in one activity I have 5 buttons. Each of these buttons make a different sound.
atm I'm doing on each buttonClicked method:

MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.click);
if(mp != null) mp.start();

MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.click2);
if(mp != null) mp.start();

etc..

is this the right way to do it, and I wonder since mp is local object, doesn't it die when the method dies, ergo no need to call mp.release() ?

note: my sounds are 0.5 sec or less and they seem to complete more often than not (haven't tested in many devices though). I'm targeting 2.1+

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your Mediaplayer reference globally need to assign mediaplayer object in the onCreate() then in button click call MediaPlayer.create(this/getApplicationContext(),R.Raw.yourfile); follow http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#StateDiagram

```
mp.reset();
                mp=MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.hummingbird);
                try {
                    mp.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
               mp.start();
```

Comment: And on onBackPressed() it is needed to release the resource otherwise memory issue arises if(mp.isPlaying()){
   mp.stop();
   mp.release();
  }

Comment: each button calls another activity and finish() on the current activity. are you sure I *have* to call release and all this stuff that will make my code 5 times bigger? And if I have too, how can I make it somehow global and write it in one place? ps I don't see you check if mp == null isn't that necessary too?